# Need Help Regarding Classes

Tags: c++, oop

Its my first **Object Oriented Program**(I have been programming in C).I have to make **a program which marks the attendance of the user when he signs in to the software**.
Here is some details of the program:

> The program starts and asks the user
>   to enter his ID and password.If the
>   user has entered the correct
>   password,the program automatically
>   marks his attendance and shows him
>   options to view to calender,history of
>   his attendance.

Now I want to decide what classes should I make and what features should I bind with them.Please help me out.If I lack something regarding the details please let me know.
Thanks

Comment: Can you give some more details on what exactly you are looking for? The question as of now is very vast.

Comment: It would help if you elaborated on both the task at hand as well as your programming background. "my first OOP" could mean anything from "I'm new to programming" to "I'm an expert C programmer and just need the right hints in how to utilize OOP"

Comment: I have added some details.Please give me some feedback before closing the question.Thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first glance, you'd find the following classes useful:

Student: Each user object should have a username and a password, and a way to validate an entered password.  This might look like:

```
class Student
{
private:
  string username;
  string password;
public:
  bool isPasswordCorrect(const string& passwordAttempt) const;
};
```

Course: Each course should have a list of dates the course will be held.

You'll need a place to track whether a particular student showed up.  I'd put this in the Course as well: each Course will need a list of students enrolled, and a way to track which students showed up on which days.

You don't need anything more to display a calendar, as you have all the data necessary.  The Course has the dates it is held, and whether a particular student showed up each day.

Comment: one could argue that the student class shoult not hold the password.

Comment: @Max: sounds like homework.  Unfortunately, this is probably what the teacher is expecting his/her students to produce...

Comment: @Max: Very true!  I erred on the side of simplicity because of the learning/homework nature of the question.

Comment: and Max: Thanks for the advice.Actually I am implementing a client server model,so I will put the password in the server computer

Comment: @fahad: Details like that are great to put in your question, next time!

Answer (score 1):

You will need **the same classes** you would have needed have you been **programming it in C**.

If you were writing it in C, you would have structures describing the "things" in the program. The same will be classes in C++ and the functions that would manipulate them will be their methods. Because all of that is just syntactic sugar to reduce typing a bit and make the intentions clearer.

Comment: Although true, this doesn't really answer the question.